# What would be the climate of a greater Antarctica?

Tags: climate, geography

I am thinking of a scenario about a supplementary piece of land on the coast of Antarctica which straddles north of the Antarctic circle with a mountain range, possibly entirely shielding it from climatic influences from the south. But what would be the climate of this band of land? Subpolar? Continental? Subantarctic? I am basing it on the Köppen climate chart. The new extension basically looks like this:

[image]

so, what would the new climate look like?

Comment: The [Antarctic Peninsula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antarctic_Peninsula) "straddles north of the Antarctic circle". And it does have mountains. The climate is, well, Antarctic.

Comment: Now AlexP you could have had that be an answer and had a map and circled the Antarctic Peninsula in red with red arrows pointing to it.  Then an image of Fiji to show the climate.  You know you would have been swimming in upvotes, mine the first of them.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the size of your additional piece of Antarctica. If it extends far enough north to disrupt the [Antarctic Circumpolar Current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antarctic_Circumpolar_Current), then that will no longer keep warmer ocean water away from Antarctica, and the climate of the whole of Antarctica will warm up.

If your additional land isn't big enough to do that, then its climate will be similar to that of the Antarctic Peninsula: very cold and dry.